# Insert image with apache-poi in a .word file, increase the image size

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new with Apache and I am checking that the image that I insert with the picture is resized in the word document. I am using the example that comes in the Apache documentation, just modified. The image is considerably enlarged from the original size and when the created .word document is opened, the picture is shown  resized on document and I find no explanation, when I am forcing the size the picture should be.

Below is the code used:

```
public class SimpleImages {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument()) {
            XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();

            XWPFRun r = p.createRun();

            for (String imgFile : args) {
                int format;

                if (imgFile.endsWith(".emf")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_EMF;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".wmf")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_WMF;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".pict")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PICT;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".jpeg") || imgFile.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".png")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".dib")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_DIB;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".gif")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_GIF;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".tiff")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_TIFF;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".eps")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_EPS;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".bmp")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_BMP;
                } else if (imgFile.endsWith(".wpg")) {
                    format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_WPG;
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Unsupported picture: " + imgFile +
                            ". Expected emf|wmf|pict|jpeg|png|dib|gif|tiff|eps|bmp|wpg");
                    continue;
                }

                r.setText(imgFile);
                r.addBreak();
                try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(imgFile)) {

                    BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(new File(imgFile));
                    int anchoImagen          = bimg.getWidth();
                    int altoImagen         = bimg.getHeight();
                    System.out.println("anchoImagen: " + anchoImagen);
                    System.out.println("altoImagen: " + anchoImagen);

                    r.addPicture(is, format, imgFile, Units.toEMU(anchoImagen), Units.toEMU(altoImagen)); 
                }
                r.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
            }

            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\W_Ejm_Jasper\\example-poi-img\\src\\main\\java\\es\\eve\\example_poi_img\\images.docx")) {
                doc.write(out);
                System.out.println(" FIN " );
            }
        }
    }


}
```

the image inside the word

[image]

the original image is (131 * 216 pixels):

[image]

the image is scaled in the word

[image]

Comment: The measurement unit in [Units.toEMU](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/Units.html#toEMU-double-) is points, not pixels. Try `Units.toEMU(Units.pixelToPoints(anchoImagen))` and `Units.toEMU(Units.pixelToPoints(altoImagen))`. Or  `Units.pixelToEMU(anchoImagen)` and `Units.pixelToEMU(altoImagen)`.

Comment: Great answer, Both solutions worked. Thank you very much